# ASP.NET MVC Html.ValidationSummary in partiallyrendered view (form)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I have form in another(shared/partial) view to have the ability to render it from different ActionViews. In that partial view I have Html.ValidationSummary. But as I found Html.ValidationSummary does not work from partial view.

Can you please help me to find the solution?

Comment: Can you post your code as I am rendering a partial view within my main page/form and Html.ValidationSummary() works fine for me.